# Setting a circular connection bar between a rounded rectangular and circular pair of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

The presented mind map is just supposed to possess a leaf child with rounded rectangular shape. I'm in trouble with deserving connection of the aforementioned child to its corresponding typically-circular parent:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[paperwidth=25cm,paperheight=20cm,hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1cm]{geometry}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}

\tikzset{conc/.style={rectangle, white, draw=red, fill=red, rounded corners=20pt}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
    node[concept] (mmm) {Neurocognitive robotic brain}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[level distance=260, minimum size=4cm, concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept] (biomech) {Biomechatronics}
    }
    child[level distance=200, minimum size=4cm, concept color=blue] {
      node[concept] {DNF-manipulated cognitive matters}
      [clockwise from=15]
      child[level distance= 180, minimum size=4cm] { node[concept] {Introduction to neuroinformatics} }
      child[level distance= 180, minimum size=4cm] { node[concept] {Neural control of movement \& Motor Learning} }
      child[level distance= 180, minimum size=4cm] { node[concept] {Signal \& information processing: modeling, filtering, learning} }
    }
    child[level distance=200, minimum size=4cm, concept color=red] {
      node[concept] {Supplementary perspective}
      [clockwise from=-90]
      child[level distance= 180, minimum size=4cm] { node[concept] {Probabilistic Artificial Intelligence} }
      child[level distance= 180, minimum size=4cm] { node[concept] {Dynamic Programming \& Optimal Control} }
      child[level distance=135, minimum size= 3cm] { node[conc] {Optimal \& Learning Control for Autonomous Robots} }
    }
    child[level distance= 260, minimum size=4cm, concept color=orange] {
      node[concept] (morph) {Neuromorphic engineering I \& II}
    };

    \path (mmm)--node[sloped, green, above=0.5cm, align=center]{\bfseries Mechanical \& integration \\ \bfseries aspects}(biomech);
    \path (mmm)--node[sloped, orange, above=0.5cm, align=center]{\bfseries Electrical \& implementation \\ \bfseries facets}(morph);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I know that the issue might be solved by right setting of a **circle connection bar**, But I couldn't apply the desired anchor settings, such considerably that the docking would be done, perfectly.

Would you please, kindly, guide me to devise the required connection bar?...

Minor issue: *I'd just selected the "minimum size" of the children, such that most of the words, within the labels do not need to be hyphenated. But in the case of middle left hand side label, "Programming" has been 
hyphenated, in a wrong manner. What kind of setting should be taken into account for resolve this case?*

[image]

Comment: You can always add a - or \-  where you want it.  (I take it you use programme instead of program?)

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I have not actually added that hyphen, you know! It's just, automatically, inserted by LaTeX, whereas I would like to have the word in a complete form as "Programming", not hyphenated as "Program-ming". How can I get rid of that?!

Comment: \mbox{Programming}

Comment: Your kindness...

Comment: Actually, the result is off center.  A better solution is to use [text width=2cm] in the node.  It seems that text width does not automatically change with minimum size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea was to add an empty circle with the same radius as the rounded corner to the mindmap, then overlay the node containing the text.  The tricky bit was that `(place holder.south east)` is not the same location as `(place holder.south -| place holder.east)`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[paperwidth=25cm,paperheight=20cm,hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1cm]{geometry}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}

\tikzset{conc/.style={rectangle, text=white, draw=red, fill=red, rounded corners=20pt}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
    node[concept] (mmm) {Neurocognitive robotic brain}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[level distance=260, minimum size=4cm, concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept,text width=4cm] (biomech) {Biomechatronics}
    }
    child[level distance=200, minimum size=4cm, concept color=blue] {
      node[concept,text width=4cm] {DNF-manipulated cognitive matters}
      [clockwise from=15]
      child[level distance= 180, minimum size=4cm] { node[concept,text width=4cm] {Introduction to neuroinformatics} }
      child[level distance= 180, minimum size=4cm] { node[concept,text width=4cm] {Neural control of movement \& Motor Learning} }
      child[level distance= 180, minimum size=4cm] { node[concept,text width=4cm] {Signal \& information processing: modeling, filtering, learning} }
    }
    child[level distance=200, minimum size=4cm, concept color=red] {
      node [concept] {Supplementary perspective}
      [clockwise from=-90]
      child[level distance= 180, minimum size=4cm] { node[concept,text width=4cm] {Probabilistic Artificial Intelligence} }
      child[level distance= 180, minimum size=4cm] { node[concept,text width=4cm] {Dynamic Programming \& Optimal Control} }
      child[level distance=110, minimum size=40pt] {node (place holder) [circle,fill=red]{} }
    }
    child[level distance= 260, minimum size=4cm, concept color=orange] {
      node[concept,text width=4cm] (morph) {Neuromorphic engineering I \& II}
    };
    \path (mmm)--node[sloped, green, above=0.5cm, align=center]{\bfseries Mechanical \& integration \\ \bfseries aspects}(biomech);
    \path (mmm)--node[sloped, orange, above=0.5cm, align=center]{\bfseries Electrical \& implementation \\ \bfseries facets}(morph);

    \node[conc,align=center,text width=2cm,inner sep=5mm,above left] at (place holder.south -| place holder.east)
      {Optimal \& Learning Control for Autonomous Robots};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: The recent update does present a relative coordination (instead of the former absolute one) and is, consequently, a better solution... Good job...